# Ethernet (intranet) and Wi-Fi (internet) to work simulatenously

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, internet, intranet

I have seen a couple of questions about this, but I am so limited in my networking knowledge that I have been unable to get those solutions to work for me.

I am trying to connect to an intranet so that I can navigate to internal sites (such as Sharepoint, etc.), but I also need to be able to access my internet over a Wi-Fi connection, which is a 3G Mi-Fi.

What's currently happening is that, when I have the ethernet cable plugged in and Wi-Fi on at the same time, my internet works, but I cannot access the intranet. And it is really a huge pain to switch between the two.

My network details are below (not sure what other details would be needed?):

Wireless:

```
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.102 (preferred)
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 192.168.1.1
```

Wired:

```
Default Gateway: 172.23.42.1
IPv4 Address: 172.23.42.165 (preferred)
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 172.24.130.12
```

My Operating System is Windows 7.

**Edit - Additional Info:**

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
15...60 67 20 52 19 f8 ......Intel(R) Centrino(R) Advanced-N 6205
19...60 67 20 52 19 f9 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #2
16...60 67 20 52 19 f9 ......Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter
14...d4 be d9 6a 63 f0 ......Broadcom NetXtreme 57xx Gigabit Controller
18...74 e5 43 54 5d a4 ......Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
 1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
26...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
11...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
23...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #6
25...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #8
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
 Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.101    281
        0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.23.42.1    172.23.42.164    276
      127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    172.23.42.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     172.23.42.164    276
  172.23.42.164  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.23.42.164    276
  172.23.42.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.23.42.164    276
    172.23.45.0    255.255.255.0      172.23.42.1    172.23.42.164     21
    192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.101    281
  192.168.1.101  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.101    281
  192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.101    281
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.23.42.164    276
      224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.101    281
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.23.42.164    276
255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.101    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
  172.23.45.0    255.255.255.0      172.23.42.1       1
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
 1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
14    276 fe80::/64                On-link
15    281 fe80::/64                On-link
14    276 fe80::7d76:b186:8068:d63a/128
                                On-link
15    281 fe80::d0f1:717e:6cbb:fa95/128
                                On-link
 1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
14    276 ff00::/8                 On-link
15    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
None
```

Please advise.

Comment: Please draw a diagram to describe your network layout.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add static routes for the intranet network.

Example: (from a CMD box)

```
route add 172.23.45.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.23.42.1 -p
```

172.23.45.0 is the network you want to reach.
172.23.42.1 is the gateway that will get you there.
-p to make it persistent, it will remain after you restart your computer.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I have done that and the intranet is now working, but the internet (personal Wi-Fi) is not. I do have limited internet access over the ethernet cable, but things like my Outlook won't connect/Dropbox won't sync/I'm unable to use Internet Download Manager because everything asks for a proxy. Is there a way to test whether I've implemented your suggestion correctly?

Comment: You need to set the priority order of your Network Adapters so that the Wi-Fi is the first. You can do it with: Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change adapter settings (from the left panel). And then press ALT to show the menu. Go to the Advanced Menu -> Advanced Settings. Move your wireless connection to the Top.

Comment: Thanks. I have been into the adapter settings and all of the Wireless connections were already at the top of the list. So I just made sure that the Wi-Fi connection I'm using is at the very top. But the issue remains - when the ethernet cable is plugged in, my Wi-Fi doesn't work and the browser asks me for proxy username and password. Was the 'example' you typed in your answer above, exactly what I needed to type? Because I added it exactly as you'd written it.

Comment: Yes, you only need to change the subnetwork that you need. How many networks does your intranet have? please run "route print" from a CMD box and copy-paste it in your question.

Comment: Okay, I have done so.

Comment: Change the metric of your WiFi connection so that is lower than you Ethernet connection.

Comment: Thanks, Cesar, I have tried that before. But for some reason it only worked temporarily. I haven't been able to get it to work since.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that you have two default routes (0.0.0.0).

So I'm clear, your Internet connection is via the wireless interface (*192.168.1.x/24*) and your intranet is via the wired interface (*172.23.42.x/24*). Is that correct? I'm further assuming that your intranet exists entirely at *172.23.42.x/24* and that *172.23.45.x* doesn't actually exist. (Not sure where @Cesar got that from). Note: The '/24' annotation is shorthand for a 24-bit netmask, or *255.255.255.0*.

On the assumption that the above is accurate, you need to delete the default route for the intranet interface.

```
route delete 0.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.23.42.1
```

The following route, from your routing table, takes care of getting intranet traffic to the right place:

```
172.23.42.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     172.23.42.164    276
```

Comment: But you'll have to do this ROUTE DELETE as shown above each time you connect the adapters (I assume one or both may be USB).

Comment: You are correct. It would be fairly simple to wire it up to a Windows event, however. In Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client/Operational, event Id 50058 is "Your computer was successfully assigned an address from the network, and it can now connect to other computers." @Amy, if you need help setting it up, I can get you some screenshots.

Comment: Thanks, BillP3rd. You are correct - the internet is via wireless and intranet is via wired.  I tried your suggestion, but it said "Route deletion failed: Element not found". Not sure where I'm going wrong?