# Windows 7 - 2 simultaneous network connections

Tags: windows-7, networking, wired-networking

I have two (onboard) ethernet adapters that I would like to use to access both a LAN (used to communicate with a highspeed camera) and the internet.

After implementing recommendations from these two threads: [Multiple network connections on Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/313679/multiple-network-connections-on-windows-7) and [Ethernet (intranet) and Wi-Fi (internet) to work simulatenously](https://superuser.com/questions/707623/ethernet-intranet-and-wi-fi-internet-to-work-simulatenously), I've still only been met with limited success.

I have the adapters configured as follows

LAN

```
Default Gateway: blank
IPv4 Address: 192.168.0.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: blank
```

Internet

```
Default Gateway: 172.79.72.1
IPv4 Address: 172.79.72.127
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
DNS: 172.79.2.1
```

I have the interface metrics for the LAN and internet set to 1 and 2000, respectively. In addition, in Windows 7's advanced networking setting I have the LAN adapter set to be accessed before the internet.

This has all been done because whenever the internet connection is active, I (somewhat) lose connection with the LAN. I say somewhat because with the internet active I cannot connect to the camera through its software; however, it does reply to pings through the command prompt. What's more strange is that in order to fix the problem, not only do I have to disable the internet connection, but I must also reboot the computer. Simply restarting the camera software after disabling the internet does not solve it, so for this reason I suspect Windows is the culprit.

Here are my routing tables

Internet working/LAN broken

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...f4 6d 04 9b 91 4f ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
 10...f4 6d 04 9b 94 35 ......Realtek PCI GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.79.72.1    172.79.72.127   2256
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      172.79.72.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     172.79.72.127   2256
    172.79.72.127  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.79.72.127   2256
    172.79.72.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.79.72.127   2256
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
      192.168.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     172.79.72.127   2256
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     172.79.72.127   2256
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.79.72.1  Default
===========================================================================
```

No Internet/LAN working

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...f4 6d 04 9b 91 4f ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
      192.168.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.0.1    257
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      172.79.72.1  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Any help with this (very frustrating) problem would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: My guess is that the camera software is written poorly. Try swapping the configuration of the network interfaces. With this I mean the WAN interface becomes the LAN interface and vice versa. Something else that is weird is that the 2 NICs have the same OID that belongs to Asus. You would expect the OIDs to be from Intel and Realtek. Perhaps some drivers or software from Asus is doing something flacky?

Comment: I've tried swapping to the WAN and LAN interfaces to no avail. The matching OIDs from ASUS make sense since it is an ASUS mobo. I will trying updating both adapters' drivers. More evidence that its not the camera software is that I have two (independent) pieces of software that fail to talk to the camera; however, they could both be equally crappy.

Comment: Make a backup of your routing table. Flush it all except the gateway. Then add **192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1**   Restore from back if it fails.

Comment: @cybernard No luck. Tried clearing the active routes, and then added what you recommended as a persistent route (got an error when trying to add it as active). Couldn't ping the LAN member any more.